# What's going on in this scala code? Callback functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Taken from Apache Spark, Dataset.scala (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0c47e274ab8c286498fa002e2c92febcb53905c6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala)

Line 2132:

```
/**
  * Returns the number of rows in the [[Dataset]].
  * @group action
  * @since 1.6.0
  */
def count(): Long = withCallback("count", groupBy().count()) { df =>
  df.collect(needCallback = false).head.getLong(0)
}
```

Line 2393:

```
/**
  * Wrap a Dataset action to track the QueryExecution and time cost, then report to the
  * user-registered callback functions.
  */
private def withCallback[U](name: String, df: DataFrame)(action: DataFrame => U) = {
  try {
      df.queryExecution.executedPlan.foreach { plan => plan.resetMetrics()
    }
    val start = System.nanoTime()
    val result = action(df)
    val end = System.nanoTime()
    sqlContext.listenerManager.onSuccess(name, df.queryExecution, end - start)
    result
  } catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    sqlContext.listenerManager.onFailure(name, df.queryExecution, e)
    throw e
  }
}
```

What is going on here? I don't understand how count() is somehow both equal to withCallback and has a body; somehow it's being called on the dataframe returned by withCallback, but I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: This is [Scala Currying](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `count()` method doesn't actually have its own body. What looks like the body of the `count()` is really a function literal, which defines the 'action' argument of `withCallback`. `count()` itself is, strictly speaking, just a call to the method `withCallback(name, df)(action)`. (Methods can have multiple argument lists in Scala.) The value of `withCallback` is `result`, which is whatever the `action` function evaluates to.

However, the "confusion" you are experiencing is intentional. This idiom -- a method that has a terminal argument list whose type is either a function or a by-name value -- allows one to define what syntactically look like language extensions. We are accustomed to languages having special syntax like...

```
try {
  // your code here
}
```

In Scala, you can write your own function like...

```
// don't ask me why you would want to do this
def unreliably[T]( operation : =>T ) : Option[T] = {
   if (scala.math.random < 0.1) Some(operation) else None
}
```

...that users could call like

```
unreliably {
  // your code here
}
```

It looks just like new language syntax! To make it more like your motivating example, we could modify the definition to have to argument lists...

```
// don't ask me why you would want to do this
def unreliably[T]( probability : Double )( operation : =>T ) : Option[T] = {
   if (scala.math.random < probability) Some(operation) else None
}
```

Now, we could call the function as...

```
unreliably( probability = 0.9 ) {
  // your code here
}
```

...and there'd be a 90% chance that your code would get executed. The code defines an expression, not just some valueless statement, so you could also write

```
val result = unreliably( probability = 0.9 ) {
   "great day"
}
```

`result` would be of type `Option[String]`, so you might follow that with...

```
println(s"""It's a ${result.getOrElse("terrible day")}.""")
```

Now, via your own little "language extension" (that's really just a funny way to call a function), you have a nice little program that makes you happy nine days out of ten.

Comment: @luigi-plinge thank you for editing away my embarrassments!